# improving search speed results - swift tableviewcontroller

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, search

I'm building personal weather app where the users can pick cities and show the weather temperature.

I'm using a search in this JSON file:

[cities.json](https://github.com/lutangar/cities.json/blob/master/cities.json)

I'm using the following code for the search:

searching extention:

```
extension SearchUI: UISearchResultsUpdating {
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!)
}
```

filtering function:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
    filteredCountries = countries.array!.filter { country in
        return country["name"].stringValue.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchText.lowercased())
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

my cellForRowAt function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell : UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "countryCell")


    var data: JSON

    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        data = filteredCountries[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        data = countries[indexPath.row]
    }

    let countryName = data["country"].stringValue
    let countrycity = data["name"].stringValue
    //data1.append(data["name"].stringValue)
    cell?.textLabel?.text = countrycity
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = countryName

    return cell!
}
```

the search process in my app is very slow and Im facing with a slow input by the keyboard during the filtering.

for notice:
countries - is a JSON object

thanks you all!

Comment: What do you mean countries is a JSON object? How/when exactly do you parse your JSON and how do you represent the JSON object in Swift?

Comment: The filterContentForSearchText method is being called every time the search text is changing which is then doing another search of the full country data set and then reloading the table view.  All this is going to take time and so each key press is held up while it happens.  There are different options to overcome it depending on how complex you want to get but basically you can put the searching on a background thread and updating the main thread when it's complete.  If you do that though to have to cancel previous ones or ensure they finish before the next one.

Comment: can you show me some example of what you mean

Answer (score 0):

parsing:

```
countries = try! JSON(data: NSData(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "cities_with_countries", ofType: "json")!)! as Data)
```